# My android app update rejected because of Invalid Encryption Declaration

Tags: android, google-maps, updates

I just released a new version in my android app and got the following email from google that the app was rejected.  In the email, they wrote that my application has an http url, so my application does not comply with the security policy, but when I looked at the links in my application, I saw that there was no http url.  I can't find the problem.  I filled out an objection form to the Google team, but I still could not get detailed information.  Please help me, how can i solve the problem?
[App rejection email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zd1Z.jpg)

To solve my problem and release my app version again.

Answer (score 1):

as you have declared wrong information in the data safety form.

**It is clearly mentioned in the mail that :**

> you have mentioned in data safety form that data is encrypted in
> transit but google has found that it's not.

### Solution

1. Either update the data safety form by filling it again with correct values.
2. Or encrypt the data before transit in your app.

When you will update the data safety form and submit it. The review will be done again by Google and this process usually takes 5-10 days for the review to complete and your app to again come live.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried the first of the solutions you mentioned, the update is accepted that way, but it does not appear as a safe application in the Play Store.  I also made an examination in the application for the 2nd solution proposal, but the data is encrypted and I could not find the source of the problem.  I could not come across the url related to the maps specified in the mail.

Comment: You can raise a ticket on play console to know more about this.

Comment: If this answer has helped you, Kindly mark it as correct answer. So that someone else can get help in future.